# Next13: Use the API folder or make calls directly in a server component?

Tags: typescript, next.js, async-await

I have begun using Next 13, and I'm trying to figure out whether or not there is any point of making api calls to the api folder using [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers). Since I have server components, the question is, why would/should I send calls through the api folder, if I can just do it directly in the server component? Here is a code example representing the two scenarios:

Example 1: Making fetch calls directly in a server component

```
// This is in app/page.tsx
const getData = async () => {
  const BASE_URL = getKotlinBackendUrl() || "";
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/example_endpoint`, {cache: 'no-store'})
  });

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log('ERROR FETCHING DATA FROM BACKEND');
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: response.text() },
      { status: response.status }
    );
  }

  return await response.json();

};

const Home = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  // Do something with the data
  return (
    <main>
      Hello World
    </main>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Example 2: Making api calls via the api folder

```
// app/page.tsx

const Home = async () => {

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/example_endpoint', {
    cache: 'no-store',
  });
  const data = (await response.json()).data;
  // Do something with the data

  return (
    <main>
      Hello world!
    </main>
  );
};
export default Home;

// app/api/endpoint/route.ts

export async function GET() {
  const BASE_URL = getKotlinBackendUrl() || '';
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/example_endpoint`)

  const data = await response.json();

  return NextResponse.json({ data }, { status: response.status });
}
```

My question is, since both of them are running server-side, what is the difference, and what are the tradeoffs? To me it seems that Example 2 is the same thing with extra steps, and more complication. If I put the getData() function from Example 1 in a different file and export it, then I'll have the same reusability that I get from having my logic in the api folder. As I currently view it, there seems to be very little point of using the api folder in Next 13, since it just complicates the code and increases the amount of await/.json(), but I'm curious to know if I'm wrong.

Also, and this is just an additional thing, I couldn't get the getData() function in Example 1 working when trying to return `NextResponse.json(...)` like I do in Example 2. Too many awaits and .json()'s. Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

Server components have not really given you the option to interact with them from the client side until now (only via [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions), which are currently in alpha).

```
// example of a server action
export default async function ServerComponent(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  async function addTodo(todo: Partial<TODO>): Promise<TODO> {
    "use server":
    // ...
  }
  return <ClientComponent action={addTodo} />;
}
```

Let's take the following example, you have a client side component called `LoginButton` that should call an external API and uses the public API key to access the external login API.

Given the fact that you really shouldn't use server actions in production yet, you would do something like the following:

```
// the route handler calling your API
export default async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  // ...
}
```

Here you can call the external resolver without the client needing to access sensitive data like the public API key without it needing to be exposed directly to the client, you can almost look at it like a proxy of some sorts.

```
// the client side component
export default function LoginButton(): JSX.Element {
  const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      // ...
    });
    // ...
  });
  
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Login</button>;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the Next 13 server components shouldn't be used in production, i.e. the Example 2 in the question is the correct implementation? Regardless, are there any other differences/benefits to using either approach?

Comment: No. As stated above "server actions" are still in alpha and should not be used in production yet, server components are production ready. Yes there are benefits, because without server actions you wouldn't be able to mutate data via server components.

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I understood this correctly, get requests can be done directly in server components, but POST, PUT, DELETE, etc, which require server actions to be done in server components, should be done via the api folder?

Comment: While server actions are still in alpha stage, yes. Because mutations are most likely to be caused by a user clicking something etc.